# Подсчёт одинаковых элементов идущих подряд

Tags: python, циклы, for, производительность

Задача, такая: есть список двух разных значений, здесь 0 и 1. Нужно составить список количества нулей идущих подряд (что-то вроде "комбо" из нулей). Мой код с использованием цикла:

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] 

zeroes_combo = []
count_zeroes = 0
for value in data:
    if value == 0:
        count_zeroes += 1
    else:
        # сброс счётчика, здесь value == 1
        if count_zeroes > 0:
            zeroes_combo.append(count_zeroes)
            count_zeroes = 0

# Добавление последних значений
if count_zeroes > 0:
    zeroes_combo.append(count_zeroes)

print(zeroes_combo) # результат: [1, 3, 2]
```

Можно как-то эту задачу переделать без использования цикла? C pandas может или другими инструментами.. А то с перебором элементов в цикле и сравнением  медленно получается.

Answer (score 3):

**вариант 1 (повышенной извратности):**

```
res = [v for v in map(len, ''.join(map(str, data)).split('1')) if v != 0]
```

**вариант 1.1 (без цикла `for`):**

```
res = list(filter(lambda v: v != 0, map(len, ''.join(map(str, data)).split('1'))))
```

**вариант 1.2 (с регулярочкой):**

```
import re
res = list(map(len, re.findall(r'0+', ''.join(map(str, data)))))
```

**вариант 2 (без строк):**

```
tmp = [-1] + [i for i, v in enumerate(data + [1]) if v == 1]
res = [tmp[i] - tmp[i - 1] - 1 for i in range(1, len(tmp)) if tmp[i] - tmp[i - 1] > 1]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за разные варианты. Быстрее чем мой оказался только последний "вариант 2 (без строк)". А если как-то всё через numpy проделать это может ускорить работу, не знаете?

Comment: ну первые через строки конечно медленнее будут ибо строки
но опять же - если надо быстрый вариант, то он будет в несколько строк, т.е. могу еще вариант 3 тогда сделать :)
на счет Numpy - надо подумать, там скорость за свет просто уже предоставленных скомпилированных функций будет

Comment: На самом деле у меня не, 0 и 1, а 2 строковых значений, но в принципе не проблема перевести их в 0 и 1. Вот нужно чтобы быстрее чем мой вариант был. Пусть не читабельный не изящный.. Если есть мысли,  то буду очень благодарен. Вот в numpy, pandas не знаю какие есть методы чтобы решить мою задачу.. уже предложили один вариант с pandas это ужас.. раз в 25 медленнее

Comment: а если строковые то может все таки регулярки попробовать - это же очень быстрый и мощный инструмент?

Comment: Я не знаю, конечно, правильно ли я делаю. Но я примитивно модулем time,  с помощью, perf_counter() делаю. В Вашем варианте реуглярных там же преобразование в строки, я даже вынес за точку отсчета map(str, data). Он всё равно медленнее других

Comment: А Вы вроде 3 вариант добавили. удалили уже? что-то на секунду видел

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот вам через pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
s = pd.Series(data)
res = s[s==0].groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).agg(len).values
```

res:

```
[1 3 2]
```

Comment: очень медленный вариант к сожалению, но спасибо:(

Comment: @Misha а какие у вас объемы данных? на малых объемах pandas использовать вообще нет смысла для таких задач. а на больших, уверен, pandas порвет всех.

Comment: Время тестировал, на сгенерированом списке таком же, только не этот маленький, а на рандоме 70млн значений, series, я сформировал до начала точки отсчета. Всё равно медленнее раз в 25 получается

Comment: Может я не так тестирую.. Я обычным модулем time. Попробуйте, если не сложно мой код и ваш запустить, только сгенерируйте, побольше рандомных значений. Или 70 млн это тоже мало для пандас? не очень разбираюсь к сожалению

Comment: @Misha 70млн - хороший сет, я проверил, pandas действительно справляется плохо. вероятно потому, что это все-таки не векторизированные  функции, а реально последовательная итерация.

Answer (score 0):

на всякий случай, еще вариант через itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x==0) if k]
```

Comment: не такой медленный как pandas, конечно, но мой быстрее. всё равно спасибо